# Python Adding one hour to time.time()

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi i want to add one hour to Python time.time().

My current way of doing it is :

```
t = int(time.time())
expiration_time = t + 3600
```

Is this considered bad for any reasons?
If so is there a better way of doing this easily.

Comment: You may consider using [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) and [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

Comment: `time().time()`? Do you mean `time.time()`?

Comment: Sounds alright. Why do you worry ?

Comment: Yeah i meant time.time(). Thanks.

Comment: The only thing I'd recommend different from your current solution (not saying there is or isn't a better one) is doing `t + (60 * 60)` for readability...not many people memorize the number of seconds in larger intervals.

Comment: @abc I worry because time manipulation has always been a hard thing for computers and I just wanna make sure I'm not missing anything.

Comment: @helloGo Personally I don't see any big problem in your use case.

Comment: @helloGo, I'm with abc. `time.time()` returns a timestamp, and you're just adding to it -- pretty simple. Only issue you'd run into is if you add `3600` to a time approaching the [2038 Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem), but that's a different issue ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not considered bad for any reason . I do it this way many times . Here is an example :

```
import time
t0 = time.time()
print time.strftime("%I %M %p",time.localtime(t0))
03 31 PM
t1 = t0 + 60*60
print time.strftime("%I %M %p",time.localtime(t1))
04 31 PM
```

Here are other ways of doing it using 'datetime'

```
import datetime
t1 = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
t2 = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=60)
```

Comment: +1 for simplicity. Note that datetime also supports adding seconds which might be self-evident.
E. g. `datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=15)`